# Animation on QMainWindow not working when executing just before exiting - python pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Code:-

```py
class MasterWindow(QMainWindow):
    close_if_clicked=True

    # [more code here]

    # FIXME - Animation while closing window doesn't work
    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if a0.button()==Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.close_if_clicked:
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"windowOpacity")
            self.animation.setDuration(1000)
            self.animation.setStartValue(1.0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0.0)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Type.InOutQuad)
            self.animation.start()
            QApplication.exit()
```

If i remove the `QApplication.exit()` function the animation works just fine, but currently when i click the window it just exits without the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution myself after a bit of playing around

```py
# FIXME - Animation while closing window doesn't work
    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if a0.button()==Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.close_if_clicked:
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"windowOpacity")
            self.animation.setDuration(1000)
            self.animation.setStartValue(1.0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0.0)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Type.InOutQuad)
            self.animation.finished.connect(QApplication.exit)
            self.animation.start()
```

My guess is that the the animation is just ignored because the app is gonna exit and by setting it as the end function we prevent it from ignoring.

Comment: Your guess is correct: Qt normally works asynchronously using an event loop, `animation.start()` is not blocking and it returns immediately (the animation works using the event loop and internal timers), so you were practically just calling `QApplication.quit()` immediately.